# Unexpected T_FUNCTION. I have no idea where the issue is

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am receiving an unexpected T_FUNCTION error. I know this happens usually from missing closing brackets and semi colons within functions. I can't seem to figure out where it is though.

For some reason when the server outputs the error but it never outputs the right line. Is there an online tool that will output the error on the proper line?

Here is the code I am receiving the T_function error on:

```
/**

 * Add Meta Box to Menu Editor Page.

 *

 *

 * 

 */



if ( !class_exists('JMO_Custom_Nav')) {

    class JMO_Custom_Nav {

        public function add_nav_menu_meta_boxes() {

            add_meta_box(

                'wl_login_nav_link',

                __('WishList Login'),

                array( $this, 'nav_menu_link'),

                'nav-menus',

                'side',

                'low'

            );

        }



        public function nav_menu_link() {

        ?>

            <div id="posttype-wl-login" class="posttypediv">

                <div id="tabs-panel-wishlist-login" class="tabs-panel tabs-panel-active">

                    <ul id ="wishlist-login-checklist" class="categorychecklist form-no-clear">

                         <?php $sections = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'newtheme_section_id', false);



                            foreach( $sections as $section ) { ?>



                        <li>





                            <label class="menu-item-title">

                                <input type="checkbox" class="menu-item-checkbox" name="menu-item[-1][menu-item-object-id]" value="-1"><?php echo $section; ?>

                            </label>

                            <input type="hidden" class="menu-item-type" name="menu-item[-1][menu-item-type]" value="custom">

                            <input type="hidden" class="menu-item-title" name="menu-item[-1][menu-item-title]" value="Login">

                            <input type="hidden" class="menu-item-url" name="menu-item[-1][menu-item-url]" value="<?php echo $section; ?>

                            <input type="hidden" class="menu-item-classes" name="menu-item[-1][menu-item-classes]" value="wl-login-pop">

                        </li>

                        <?php } ?>

                    </ul>

                </div>

                <p class="button-controls">

                    <span class="list-controls">

                        <a href="/wordpress/wp-admin/nav-menus.php?page-tab=all&amp;selectall=1#posttype-page" class="select-all">Select All</a>

                    </span>

                    <span class="add-to-menu">

                        <input type="submit" class="button-secondary submit-add-to-menu right" value="Add to Menu" name="add-post-type-menu-item" id="submit-posttype-wl-login">

                        <span class="spinner"></span>

                    </span>

                </p>

            </div>

        <?php } 

    }

}



$custom_nav = new JMO_Custom_Nav;



add_action('admin_init', array($custom_nav, 'add_nav_menu_meta_boxes'))
```

Comment: Why didn't you tell us which line is missing a semi-colon?

Comment: At the end of your code you missed semi colon (`;`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

find 1

```
<input type="hidden" class="menu-item-url" name="menu-item[-1][menu-item-url]" value="<?php echo $section; ?>
```

no close tag

find 2

```
    <?php }  //<<close FUNC

} //<<close class

} // << CLOSE ????  try to del this
```